# Showing the non-decreasing part of simple functions converging to measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Trying to show $S_n \leq S_{n+1}$

where $S_n(w)=\sum_{k=1}^{n2^n} \frac{k-1}{2^n} \chi_{A_{n,k}}+n\chi_{B_{n}}$ and

${A_{n,k}}= \left\{w \in A:\frac{k-1}{2^n}\leq f(w) < \frac{k}{2^n}\right\}$ where $k=1,2,...n2^n$ and

$B_n=\left\{w \in A: f(w) \geq n\right\}$.

I got the first case where $w \in A_{nk} $, but struggling to show the second case where $w \in B_n$.

I thought it was trivial since $S_n(w)=n$ when $w \in B_n$, but apparently it's not....and there are two subcases...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ an element of $B_n$. If $x$ belongs to $B_{n+1}$, then we are done since $S_n(x)=n\leqslant n+1=S_{n+1}(x)$. Now assume that $x$ does not belong to $B_{n+1}$. Then we have $n\leqslant f(x)\lt n+1$. In this case, we have $x\in\bigcup_{j=n2^{n+1}+1}^{(n+1)2^{n+1}}A_{n+1,j}  $  and we get $S_{n+1}(x)\geqslant n$.